# How To Edit .sdf file

Tags: vb.net, sdf

I have my application and I install a .sdf file and I add columns to my database. So how do I update my database without losing my Data?

Answer (score 2):

You can execute standard data definition language (DDL) commands in code at application startup.

For example:

```
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery("ALTER TABLE MyTable ADD NewColumn1 INT NULL")
```

We have done this for years in devices ranging from PocketPC to Tablets.

We used to check whether or not a database table or column existed before modifying the DB structure, but we have found it is much easier to record the current database version in a table and then just check the version on startup then make the modifications that we know are necessary between the current version in the database and the application's database version.

Comment: sorry but i didn't understand what you say

Comment: When the application is started, just execute standard SQL commands, such as Alter table, to add columns to your database.

Comment: can you tell me to location from the database i should be able to open my database manually  ????

Comment: You write this code in your application and execute it after you open your database within the application. This is just like any other SQL that you execute against the SDF, it just happens to modify the structure of the database instead of setting or retrieving values from those tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can extend/update a database schema by choosing Default Values for new columns or allow new columns to accept Nulls.

Comment: This is still not working it comes up that the colem's is not found

Comment: Can you please show us the SQL statements you are running that cause that error, ta.